# I have a CSV file . But I cant use this file

Tags: sql, database, csv, import

I have a cvs file . But when ı want import my cvs file to database ı cant . Because my datas shifts to other tables . Im using SQL Server Management Studio. I have a lot of data . How can ı import my file . [This my Csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EjeT.png) and [This is after import view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAS4H.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not use images.  Having said that, the issue is clearly the commas inside your quoted fields. How are you actually importing the file?

Comment: ım using Management Studio for this . I click the right mouse button on my database. Then ı picked Task>İmport Data. After this things , Sql server import and export Wizard appears . [link](https://www.hizliresim.com/rwwy2af) .

Comment: Are you specifying double quotes for your text qualifier? I don't know if that will work here, since you don't have quotes around all your fields.

Answer (score 0):

To handle rows which aren't loaded into table because of invalid data or format, could be handle using [a link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=&view=sql-server-ver16 specify the error file name, it will write the rows having error to error file. code should look like.

```
BULK INSERT SchoolsTemp
FROM 'C:\CSVData\Schools.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
ERRORFILE = 'C:\CSVDATA\SchoolsErrorRows.csv',
TABLOCK
)
```

Comment: I got this error "Cannot bulk load because the file "‪‪D:\Movies.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 123".